# how to fix error of "Cannot assign to property: 'setBarTintGradientColors' is a method"

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjgs.png)

I trying to set Navigationbar gradient colors using CRGradientNavigationBar library.

Comment: before someone downvote your question please put the code as text, not as image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBarTintGradientColors` is a method, meaning it must take an argument (a list  of colors). Therefore, you will need something like this instead of assignment:

```
CRGradientNavigationBar.appearance().setBarTintGradientColors(colors)
```

As a rule of thumb, whenever you have `set` in the name, it is a function, not an attribute, meaning that you will need to pass an argument instead of assign.

Comment: thank man. It work

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar
Did you write about this library?
It's old library, it doesn't update about five years. Maybe you should use other libraries?

Comment: Do you have other library to suggest that is same function  ?

Comment: @jeffchiang The best way is to use your own code. Use the code below instead of a library.